# Get slug using term id

Tags: wordpress

I need help I googled almost everything but not getting category slug using `term_id`
$term_id

Please help sorry if this question is asked before

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that searching Google for "category slug using term_id" gives get_term_by() as first results. Which allows you to get a term (what you call a "category") from it's ID, and retrieve easily the slug from the returned term object. The same documentation page gives you the fields list of the term object returned including "slug"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$term_object = get_term( $term_id );
$term_object->slug;
```

Comment: $term_object->slug;  on this it display  Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object in /

Comment: I changed the answer, this should work unless the id is not right

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$term = get_term_by('id', $id)` [see get_term_by() codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by).

Then access slug using `$term->slug`.

Comment: Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object it display this error

Comment: It means that get_term_by did not found any result. Are you sure a term with the ID you provide exists?

Comment: Not that this is the almost exact same answer i posted compared to Ash0ur, but before :)